# can't see the result in the select area

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I can't see the result in the select area

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
    $query = "SELECT cat_id, category FROM categories LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(!$result){
       echo 'Query failed : '.mysqli_error();
       exit(0);
    } 
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo '<select name="cat_id">
    ' . $row['cat_id'] . '
    </select>';
                        }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I try to add the HTML `select` tag but it still isn't working.

Comment: you need to add options to select

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good format for select

```
echo '<select name="cat_id">
    ' . $row['cat_id'] . '
    </select>';
```

It should be

```
echo '<select name="cat_id">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo  '<option value="'.$row['cat_id'] .'">'.$row['cat_id'].'</option>';
   }
echo '</select>';
```